# optimize Firestore Update query

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

Could you tell me how can I optimize below Firestore query? You can see that I have to do 2 DB request for doing the update operation. Can't I do that using single request or?

```
async updateProjectOfOwnerMember(id: string, project: Project): Promise<void> {
    let finalProjects: Project[];
    const querySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection("members").where("id", "==", id).get();
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
      const currentProjects: Project[] = doc.exists ? doc.data().projects : [];
      finalProjects = filter(currentProjects, (p: Project) => { return p.id != project.id; });//projects Without Updated Project
      finalProjects.push(project);
    });
    await this.fireStore.doc(`members/${id}`).update({ projects: finalProjects, isOwner: true });
  }
```